# Error on yii2 SelectizeTextInput widget of dosamigos dosamigos\selectize\SelectizeTextInput form

Tags: yii2, selectize.js

exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: common\models\Spot::sportsValues' in D:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\frost\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:143 Stack trace:

spot > _form file

```
use dosamigos\selectize\SelectizeTextInput;
    <?= $form->field($model, 'sportsValues')->widget(SelectizeTextInput::className(), [

        'loadUrl' => ['/sports/sports/list'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'plugins' => ['remove_button'],
            'valueField' => 'name',
            'labelField' => 'name',
            'searchField' => ['name'],
            'create' => false,
        ],
    ]) ;

    ?>
```

Spot Model

```
use creocoder\taggable\TaggableBehavior;
 public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
                TaggableBehavior::className(),

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['sportsValues', 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'sportsValues' => Yii::t('common', 'Sports'),
        ];
    }

public function getSports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sports::className(), ['id' => 'sports_id'])->viaTable('{{%sports_spot}}', ['spot_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getSportsLinks()
    {
        $sportsLinks = [];

        foreach ($this->sports as $sports) {
            $sportsLinks[] = Html::a($sports->name, ['sports', 'slug' => $sport->name]);
        }

        return implode(', ', $sportsLinks);
    }
    public static function find()
    {
        return new SpotQuery(get_called_class());
    }
```

`

SpotQuery

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
                TaggableQueryBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: This error is not about the widget. Have you got attribute named `sportsValues` in the Spot model?